# problem with gluLookAt in selecting

Tags: c#, opengl, select

Hello
This is my function that will detect hit.

```
private int[] GetSelected(int x, int y)
{
    const int max = 512;
    var Hit_Buffer = new int[max];
    var viewport = new int[4];

    Gl.glSelectBuffer(max, Hit_Buffer);
    Gl.glRenderMode(Gl.GL_SELECT);

    Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_PROJECTION);
    Gl.glPushMatrix();
    Gl.glLoadIdentity();

    Glu.gluLookAt(Distance * Math.Cos(beta) * Math.Cos(alpha)
        , Distance * Math.Cos(beta) * Math.Sin(alpha)
        , Distance * Math.Sin(beta)
        , 0, 0, 0
        , -Math.Sin(beta) * Math.Cos(alpha)
        , -Math.Sin(beta) * Math.Sin(alpha)
        , Math.Cos(beta));

    Gl.glGetIntegerv(Gl.GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);
    Glu.gluPickMatrix(x, viewport[3] - y, 1, 1, viewport);

    Glu.gluPerspective(fovY, ogl1.Width / (double)(ogl1.Height != 0 ? ogl1.Height : 1), 0.1, 100.0);
    Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_MODELVIEW);

    Gl.glInitNames();
    // render scene: a TRIANGLE
    Gl.glPushName(1);
    Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_TRIANGLES);
    Gl.glVertex3d(0, 0, 0);
    Gl.glVertex3d(0, 1, 0);
    Gl.glVertex3d(1, 0, 0);
    Gl.glEnd();
    Gl.glPopName();
    //

    Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_PROJECTION);
    Gl.glPopMatrix();
    Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_MODELVIEW);
    Gl.glFlush();

    var hits = Gl.glRenderMode(Gl.GL_RENDER);
    Array.Resize(ref Hit_Buffer, hits);

    return Hit_Buffer;
}
```

I am drawing a triangle in xy plane.
In gluLookAt, beta is camera angle from xy plane and alpha is camera angle about z.
But it just works if beta be small ( -15< beta <15 degree )!
What is wrong here?

Comment: alpha and beta are really in radians, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello again
I finally find my answer by myself! (by googling)
Here is my corrected code

```
private int[] GetSelected(int x, int y, bool debug)
{
    var hits = 0; // number of hits

    // Define select buffer
    const int max = 512;
    var Hit_buffer = new int[max];
    Gl.glSelectBuffer(max, Hit_buffer);

    var viewport = new int[4];
    Gl.glViewport(0, 0, Width, (Height != 0 ? Height : 1));
    Gl.glGetIntegerv(Gl.GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);

    if (debug)// show real scene in debug mode
        GlDraw();

    if(!debug)
        Gl.glRenderMode(Gl.GL_SELECT);

    int s = debug ? 60 : 3; // test region size

    Gl.glLoadIdentity();
    Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_PROJECTION);
    Gl.glPushMatrix();
    Gl.glLoadIdentity();

    Glu.gluPickMatrix(x, viewport[3] - y, s, s, viewport);

    Glu.gluPerspective(fovY, Width / (double)(Height != 0 ? Height : 1), 0.1, 1000.0);
    Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_MODELVIEW);

    if (debug) // test region will be shown in left-bottom corner
        Gl.glViewport(0, 0, s, s);

    #region camera
    Gl.glTranslated(Dx, Dy, 0);
    var Distance = this.Distance;// *ogl1.Height / 60.0;
    var CenterView = this.CenterView.Duplicate();
    Glu.gluLookAt(Distance * Math.Cos(beta) * Math.Cos(alpha) + CenterView.x
        , Distance * Math.Cos(beta) * Math.Sin(alpha) + CenterView.y
        , Distance * Math.Sin(beta) + CenterView.z
        , CenterView.x
        , CenterView.y
        , CenterView.z
        , -Math.Sin(beta) * Math.Cos(alpha)
        , -Math.Sin(beta) * Math.Sin(alpha)
        , Math.Cos(beta));
    #endregion

    if (debug) // draw a bacground in left-bottom corner
    {
        ChangeColor(Color.Blue);
        Glu.gluSphere(Glu.gluNewQuadric(), 50, 50, 50);
        Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
        Gl.glVertex3d(-10, -10, -10);
        Gl.glVertex3d(-10, 10, -10);
        Gl.glVertex3d(10, 10, -10);
        Gl.glVertex3d(10, -10, -10);
        Gl.glEnd();
    }

    Gl.glInitNames();

    // render scene
    foreach (var b in Bodies)
    {
        Gl.glPushName(b.id);
        var bb = b.Duplicate();
        bb.color = Color.Red;
        bb.Draw();
        Gl.glPopName();
    }
    //

    Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_PROJECTION);
    Gl.glPopMatrix();
    Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_MODELVIEW);
    Gl.glFlush();

    if (!debug) 
        hits = Gl.glRenderMode(Gl.GL_RENDER);

    // process hits
    int[] Res = { };
    int startRecord = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < hits; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Hit_buffer[startRecord]; j++)
        {
            Array.Resize(ref Res, Res.Length + 1);
            Res[Res.Length - 1] = Hit_buffer[startRecord + 3 + j];
        }
        startRecord += 3 + Hit_buffer[startRecord];
    }

    return Res;
}
```

If you set the debug parameter =true, it will draw the select region in left-bottom corner.
The code may be boring, so I am gonna write main parts here

```
    // Define select buffer
    const int max = 512;
    var Hit_buffer = new int[max];
    Gl.glSelectBuffer(max, Hit_buffer);

    var viewport = new int[4];
    Gl.glGetIntegerv(Gl.GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);

    Gl.glRenderMode(Gl.GL_SELECT);

    Gl.glLoadIdentity();
    Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_PROJECTION);
    Gl.glPushMatrix();
    Gl.glLoadIdentity();

    Glu.gluPickMatrix(x, viewport[3] - y, 3, 3, viewport);

    Glu.gluPerspective(fovY, Width / (double)(Height != 0 ? Height : 1), 0.1, 1000.0);
    Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_MODELVIEW);

    Gl.glInitNames();

    // set camera (gluLookAt, ...) & draw scene

    Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_PROJECTION);
    Gl.glPopMatrix();
    Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_MODELVIEW);
    Gl.glFlush();

    var hits = Gl.glRenderMode(Gl.GL_RENDER);

    // process hits
```

Answer (score 0):

In OpenGL Y is up

For the first 3 parameters, I'd rather say :

```
      Distance * Math.Cos(beta) * Math.Cos(alpha)
    , Distance * Math.Sin(beta)
    , Distance * Math.Cos(beta) * Math.Sin(alpha)
```

And for the 3 last ones, try with (0,1,0) first.

Comment: It is not my problem! My code works well. I have problem with selection.

Answer (score 0):

Have you called gluLookAt before gluPickMatrix on purpose. Do you want to apply translations to your pick matrix? If not can you move gluPickMatrix immediately after glLoadIdentity and try if your problem gets resolved?

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yes calling gluLookAt before gluPickMatrix was wrong!